# Call by value is known as pure function how ?give reason

Tags: functional-programming

[image]I think call by value may be pure function  or impure function...

And pure function can be written through call by value or call by reference....

So according to the facts (c) should be correct  ans...

Comment: What is this, 1976? Who teaches programming languages like this?

Comment: What is your question? Please state the question in your post.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 0):

The source does not seem to talk about pure in a functional programming sense. Note it says "pure method" and not "pure function".

Call-by-value is not really a type of method either. It is a way of passing arguments. A better name might be pass-by-value. In some programming languages, like C++, one function can have both pass-by-name and pass-by-value parameters.

This leads me to speculate: Maybe "pure method" in this context is meant to say "a pure-ish/purer way of passing arguments".

I agree with your assessment that both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference can used in pure functions. In Java, passing an immutable `java.lang.String` instance does not violate purity. C++ support const parameters, that prevent the function from modifying the referenced object (within reason).

The question which You are quoting seems sketchy to me. In order to reason that something is *known* as something, You would have to quote or make a survey. And why are answer (c) and (d) identical?

Comment: "I agree with your assessment that both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference can used in pure functions" – In fact, in a pure functional language, there is no observable difference between the two. Therefore, a common strategy for functional languages is to specify them as-if they were pass-by-value (which is easier to explain), yet implement them as pass-by-reference (which is typically faster).